# Ajax POST request with Array[Byte] response

Tags: ajax, scala, post, http4s

I'm receiving an ajax POST request and need to process the body data as a ByteBuffer and respond with an Array[Byte] using Http4s (0.23.7). This is as far I have been able to put things together, although it's not working yet:

```scala
// http4s/fs2/cats imports... +
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.Channels

HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
  case ajaxRequest@POST -> Root / "ajax" / path =>
    val stream: fs2.Stream[IO, IO[Array[Byte]]] =
      ajaxRequest.body
        // 1. Convert body to InputStream (to enable converting to ByteBuffer)
        .through(fs2.io.toInputStream)
        .map { inputStream =>
          // 2. Create and populate ByteBuffer
          val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(inputStream.available)
          Channels.newChannel(inputStream).read(byteBuffer)

          // 3. Process byteBuffer with library code
          val futResult: Future[Array[Byte]] = getRpcResult(path, byteBuffer)

          // 4. Convert Future to IO (?)
          val ioResult: IO[Array[Byte]] = IO.fromFuture(IO(futResult))
          ioResult
        }

    // 5. Convert stream to Response - how?
    Ok(stream)
      // 6. Set octet-stream content type
      .map(_.withContentType(
        `Content-Type`(MediaType.application.`octet-stream`, Charset.`UTF-8`)
      ).putHeaders(`Cache-Control`(NonEmptyList.of(`no-cache`()))))
}
```

Some questions:

- Is there some overall completely different way of doing this with Http4s/fs2?
- Is there an easier way to convert ajaxRequest.body to a ByteBuffer (step 1-2)?
- Do I need to convert the Future to an IO (step 4)?
- How do I convert the stream to be used as an Ok response (step 5)?

For reference, here's how I do it in Play and Akka-Http:

```scala
// Play
def ajax(path: String): Action[RawBuffer] = {
  Action.async(parse.raw) { implicit ajaxRequest =>
    val byteBuffer = ajaxRequest.body.asBytes(parse.UNLIMITED).get.asByteBuffer
    getRpcResult(path, byteBuffer).map(Ok(_))
  }
}

// Akka-Http
path("ajax" / Remaining)(path =>
  post {
    extractRequest { req =>
      req.entity match {
        case HttpEntity.Strict(_, byteString) =>
          complete(getRpcResult(path, byteString.asByteBuffer))
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is written on top of my head and following the docs, since I can't test it right now.
*(thus it may have some typos / errors; if you find one please feel free to edit the answer and thanks!)*

```scala
HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
  case ajaxRequest @ POST -> Root / "ajax" / path =>
    val response =
      ajaxRequest.as[Array[Byte]].flatMap { byteArray =>
        IO.fromFuture(IO(
          getRpcResult(path, ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray))
        ))
      }

    Ok(response) 
}
```

Let's expand on a couple of things.

1. **http4s** supports reading and writing `Array[Byte]` out of the box, so no need to do funny things.
2. Yes, you need to convert a `Future` to `IO`; and the way you did was wrong because the `Future` was already out of control. Also, if you would know what `IO` is, what problems does it solve and why **http4s** doesn't use `Future`; you wouldn't even be asking this question.
3. You should hide that `Future` in a proper interface. This is more of general design advice more than a **http4s** specific one. That would not only make the code prettier but would make it easier to replace the legacy modules later or use a fake implementation in tests.

---

Anyways, for looking at your code and the questions you ask it is clear that you are not familiar with the **typelevel** stack, nor with the [*"Programs as Values"* paradigm](https://systemfw.org/archive.html).

Thus, first of all, I would encourage you to join the [**Typelevel** **Discord** server](https://discord.gg/yyjXBYmc) since it may be easier to help you through that platform than on **StackOverflow**.
Second, I would suggest you ask yourself why are you using that stack? Is it for self-learning? Then great, but, please, follow an appropriate learning path, instead of just trying random code *(after all, this is a completely new programming paradigm)*; it is for work? Ok but, then again, ask for support since you will be hitting one wall to another without proper guidance and you would end up hating this wonderful ecosystem; it is for another reason? Then again, think about what is the main driver and follow an appropriate plan.

---

Additionally, you may want to see if something like [**fs2-grpc**](https://github.com/typelevel/fs2-grpc) could be useful so you don't need to buffer all the request / response in memory, but rather stream everything in both ways.

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm! Yes, I'm new to the Typelevel stack, and was simply curious in comparing with Http4s which resulted in the admittedly ugly code :-). Thanks for the various pointers and thoughts - I have some home work to do. Your idea of streaming back and forth is interesting. Will ponder that too.